# Find perfect maze path, using Graph structure

Tags: java, graph, maze

I have this classes and code that solve the maze, but i don't understand why solution is written this way... it doesn't even use the graph...

Here is the GraphNode : http://pastebin.com/DMprKQAN

Here is the Graph : http://pastebin.com/ueCWqPww

Maze class:

```
public class Lavirint {
    Graph<String> g;
    int start_node; 
    int end_node;

    Hashtable<String, Integer> h;

    public Lavirint() {
        h = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();
        g= null;
    }

    void generateGraph(int rows, int columns, String[] in) {

        int num_nodes = 0;
        String key;
        for(int i=1; i<rows-1; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<columns-1; j++){
                if(in[i].charAt(j)!='#'){
                    key = i+","+j;
                    h.put(key, num_nodes);
                        if(in[i].charAt(j)=='S')
                            start_node = num_nodes;
                            if(in[i].charAt(j)=='E')
                                end_node = num_nodes;
                num_nodes++;
                }
            }
        }

        g = new Graph<String>(num_nodes);
        int x, y;
            // Generating neighbours matrix
        for(int i=1; i<rows-1; i++){ 
            for(int j=1; j<columns-1; j++){
                if(in[i].charAt(j)!='#'){
                    if(in[i].charAt(j-1)!='#'){ 
                        x = h.get(i+","+j); y = h.get(i+","+(j-1));
                        g.addEdge(x, y);
                    }
                    if(in[i].charAt(j+1)!='#'){
                        x = h.get(i+","+j); y = h.get(i+","+(j+1));
                        g.addEdge(x, y);
                    }
                    if(in[i-1].charAt(j)!='#'){
                        x = h.get(i+","+j); y = h.get((i-1)+","+j);
                        g.addEdge(x, y);
                    }
                    if(in[i+1].charAt(j)!='#'){
                        x = h.get(i+","+j); y = h.get((i+1)+","+j);
                        g.addEdge(x, y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void findPath() {
        boolean visited[] = new boolean[g.num_nodes];
        for (int i = 0; i < g.num_nodes; i++)
            visited[i] = false;
        visited[start_node] = true;
        Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
        s.push(start_node);
        int pom,pom1;
        while (!s.isEmpty() && s.peek()!=end_node) {
            pom = s.peek();
            pom1 = pom;
        for (int i = 0; i < g.num_nodes; i++) {
            if(g.adjacent(pom,i)==1){
                pom1 = i;
                if(!visited[i])
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(!visited[pom1]){
            visited[pom1] = true;
            s.push(pom1);
        }
        else
            s.pop();
        }
        Stack<Integer> os = new Stack<Integer>();
        while(!s.isEmpty())
            os.push(s.pop());
        while(!os.isEmpty()) {
            String t=null;
            Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> it=(h.entrySet()).iterator();
            int i=os.pop();
            while(it.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Integer> entry=it.next();
                if (entry.getValue()==i) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey());
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Lavirint l = new Lavirint();
        String pom = br.readLine();
        String[] ppom = pom.split(",");
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(ppom[0]);
        int columns = Integer.parseInt(ppom[1]);
        String[] in = new String[rows];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
            in[i] = br.readLine();

        l.generateGraph(rows, columns, in);

        l.findPath();
    }

}
```

I don't understand why when the Graph is being generated GraphNode.info is empty and only Edges are marked, so because it is done, finding the path() has weird solution...
All i wanna know is this is good or right approach and if i solve this maze using Char for info variable in GraphNode will be bad solution??

Test Cases:

1.

```
6,6
######
#S# E#
# # ##
#   ##
######
######
```

Answer:

```
1,1
2,1
3,1
3,2
3,3
2,3
1,3
1,4
```

2.

```
8,8
########
#  S####
# ##   #
#    # #
###### #
#####  #
#####E##
########
```

Answer:

```
1,3
1,2
1,1
2,1
3,1
3,2
3,3
3,4
2,4
2,5
2,6
3,6
4,6
5,6
5,5
6,5
```

Answer (score 0):

The `findPath()` method *does* use the graph. The graph allows you to check adjacent tiles to the one you're currently checking using the `g.adjacent()` call. (Haven't looked at the code in the links but I assume that's what it does since your algorithm works). The approach of solving the labyrinth like this seems fine to me.